# CheckPoint VPN on Ubuntu without IcedTea plugin

Tags: networking, firefox, vpn, icedtea

I was using firefox with IcedTea plugin to connect to my company CheckPoint VPN, because with snx I never succeeded to connect and don't know how to configure other vpn clients.

Now, starting from Firefox 52, IcedTea is no more supported. I kept an older version of firefox just to continue connecting, but what are the alternatives?

Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to connect to checkpoint VPN is to use 'snx'. Yes, it is ancient and requires some fiddling to run. If you have problems with it, you need to address those problems particulary.

Comment: already tried many times with snx.. always got "authentication failed"...  with another customer vpn, always checkpoint, snx successfully connect. Maybe is my company configuration, or Checkpoint gateway version.. unfortunately I cannot go more deeper ... because snx with Linux is not officially approved by my company.. the standard procedure is use windows and checkpoint software or through website..